# Do action when alarm is dismissed

Tags: alarm

I want to set an alarm with a specific label, and when that specific alarm is dismissed, I want it to launch my app. Is there any way to do that?

I'm using Kivy with jnius, so I'd appreciate responses wrt that, but any help is appreciated very much.

Comment: you could try tasker app for that. It handles such actions very neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Any automation can probably handle such tasks. Try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dreddit) (free) with its [Alarm](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/alarm.html) and [App start](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/activity_start.html) blocks.